# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error - Apache Tomcat(Restful webservice)

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

When I tried to run the below code I am getting the error...
console did not[image] show any errors.

```
public List<MailExample> getMailAttributes()
{
    List<MailExample> mailList = null;

    try
    {
        File file = new File("c:/mail.dat");
        if(!file.exists())
        {
            MailExample me = new MailExample("manoj.@webservices.com", "Test Mail", "hi this is the testing mail");
            mailList = new ArrayList<MailExample>();
            mailList.add(me);
        }
        else
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            mailList = (List<MailExample>) oos.readObject();
            oos.close();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mailList;
```

Comment: The error is not related to the code above. Your servlet settings and the related coding might have a mistake. Can you provide your servlet mappings and code?

Comment: check ur server logs

Comment: @CahitGungor i have been learning webservices. Im a beginer, for practice i downloaded the project and made an exact copy of the downloaded project and made the sufficient changes as per my requirements. the downloaded project is running properly, the exact copy of it is not working.

Comment: <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.domain</param-value>
         </init-param>
      </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

Comment: @SajanChandran thanks for the reply. Server logs folder is empty.

Comment: You will find the reason for this in your server logs, check the installation directory of your tomcat. The webpage is configured not the show details

Comment: Which **url** address you use in the browser for testing? Use that **url's last part** in your project to find the mapping through text search.   For instance if you have a url like http://localhost:8080/helloworld-webapp/helloworld, then you should find **helloword** in your project, which supposed to do the mapping.